# CSS pixel doubling on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I'm developing a responsive theme and the issue is all of the pixels are doubled on the iPhone.
I believe this is due to a retina display.

**My question is do I have to create an another style sheet ( or using media queries) by giving special values for retina only displays (dividing actual pixel size by pixel density)?**

- *All of the margins are doubled*
- *Border thickness is doubled*
- *Font size is doubled*

**Currently I have all the margins, borders ..etc. in pixels.**

For now, I'm using following java-script to control initial scale and it's working fine.

```
(function() {
  var meta = document.createElement("meta");
    meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
    var content = 'initial-scale=';
    content += 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;
    content += ',user-scalable=no';
    meta.setAttribute('content', content);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
})();
```

Can some one please tell me a solution for this?

***Edit:***

I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />` too.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">` is what you are looking for, combine this with media queries.

Comment: I have already tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />` and no luck. But the javascript code is working because it is detecting the pixel density and setting the initial scale.

Comment: This will work, for example combine it with @media (max-width:320px) {/* styles */}. This will work on an iPhone even tho the resolution is bigger then 320px's because the meta tag tells the browser to take the device width and not the actual resolution.

Comment: Sorry! but what do you mean by 'combine with'? Currently I have my 640 design inside the `@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1011px) { }` So.. how can I put your code inside that?

My issue is only doubling pixels. Detecting device width and changing layout is okay. It is working fine while I'm resizing the desktop browser.

Comment: I think you're asking me to do a 320p design and it's going to work with the 640p iPhone5. isn't it?